# Beginner struggling with PHP form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I've been learning PHP over the past few weeks and am admittedly rushing ahead of my reading somewhat to try and create a form from scratch and work out the logic in practice.

I am trying to validate form data (starting initially here with the 'name' field) using PHP before sending the user to a 'submission successful' page (and the data to a server).

I have so far managed to get the form validation working by leaving **action=""** - blank like so (instead of using **PHP_SELF** which I've read is a security risk), but the problem here is that even when filling out the form properly, it doesn't go anywhere because no action has been set.

Conversely, I've managed to send the user to a 'submission successful' page with **action=handler.php** - but doing this ignores my PHP form field validation code.

I feel I'm missing something quite obvious here as I'm not sure how to marry up the PHP validation with sending the user to a 'submission successful' page, and the data off to be stored somewhere.

The PHP at the top of my **capture.php** form page reads:

```
<?php

$name_error = '';

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
{  
  if(empty($_POST["name"]))  
  {  
       $name_error = "Please Enter Name";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["name"]))  
       {  
            $name_error = "Only Letters and whitespace";  
       }  
   }    
}  
?>
```

- this will expand to include other types of form field in time.

My html in **capture.php**:

```
<body class="capture">

<!--action code #1-->
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--action code #2-->
<!--<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">

<label for="name">Your name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label><br/>
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Joe Bloggs" name="name" maxlength="70" />  
<span class="text-danger"><?php echo $name_error; ?></span> 

</div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">

 <label for="games">Your choice</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="games">
  <option> -- </option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  </select>

  </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <input id="btn-prev" name="prev" type="prev" value="Prev">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<input id="btn-next" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next"></div>
```

Thanks for any help offered

Comment: I think the page that's doing the validation never sees the POST data. Either move the form validation to `handler.php` (redirect back upon validation error) OR set the `action` of the form element to `"capture.php"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've done your form validation use header redirects to send users to your thank you page

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["name"]))  
{  
   $name_error = "Only Letters and whitespace";  
} else {
   // no errors - redirect to success page
   header('Location:./handler.php');
}
```

That will redirect the user after your validation.
Only allow that to run if validation was successful.

Doing the redirect will also mean that a page reload will not re-submit the form.

You should really take a look at the PHP Sanitize and Validation Filters to clean and check your form inputs.

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php and
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

If you are planning on storing the name in a database, take extra care to learn how to avoid SQL Injection (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Awesome thank you. And thanks additionally for the links to cleaning the form inputs this is also something I have been researching.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is working your code , only you miss end form tag . try this code. i use same page action so in capture.php page all code here if you want to set action handler.php then add php code in handler.php and if error then redirect it to capture.php and use session or get para meter to show error

```
<?php

$name_error = '';

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error = "Please Enter Name";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["name"])) {
            $name_error = "Only Letters and whitespace";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!--action code #1-->
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--action code #2-->
    <!--<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="name">Your name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label><br/>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Joe Bloggs" name="name" maxlength="70"/>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $name_error; ?></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="games">Your choice</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="games">
                <option> --</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input id="btn-prev" name="prev" type="prev" value="Prev">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input id="btn-next" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next"></div>
</form>
```

if you want to submit your form in handler.php file then use this code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<body class="capture">

    <!--action code #1-->
    <form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!--action code #2-->
        <!--<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="name">Your name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label><br/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Joe Bloggs" name="name" maxlength="70"/>
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['form_error']['name'])) { ?>
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['form_error']['name']; ?></span>
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="games">Your choice</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="games">
                    <option>--</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>

                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['form_error']['game_error'])) { ?>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $_SESSION['form_error']['game_error']; ?></span>
                    <?php
                } ?>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input id="btn-prev" name="prev" type="prev" value="Prev">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input id="btn-next" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next"></div>
    </form>
    <?php
    unset($_SESSION['form_error']);
     ?>
```

then this is your hanlder.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$name_error = array();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error['name'] = "Please Enter Name";
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["name"])) {
            $name_error['name'] = "Only Letters and whitespace";
        }
    }

    if ($_POST["games"] == '--') {
        $name_error['game_error'] = "Please Select Game";
    }
}
if (!empty($name_error)) {
    $_SESSION['form_error'] = $name_error;
    header("Location: capture.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Yep, providing the snippet in you're question was correct, the missing </form> tag would stop it.

Also, for extending it, add to an array of errors, then you can list all items that failed validation.

Comment: check my update answer which submit form to hanlder.php file and list all error if not exit. you can change it if you want

Answer (score 0):

Just set the action of the form to capture.php
As this is where your php is at work, validating the form, this is where you want to send it!

If you want to redirect after the validation you can redirect to another page using [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header('Location: handler.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the action back to handler.php and put the validation which you have in capture.php at the top of handler.php.

capture.php

```
    <body class="capture">

    <!--action code #1-->
    <form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--action code #2-->
    <!--<form action="handler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">-->

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">

    <label for="name">Your name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label><br/>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Joe Bloggs" name="name" maxlength="70" />  
     <?php
     if(isset($_GET["name_error"])) { ?>  
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $name_error; ?></span> 
      <?php } ?>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">

     <label for="games">Your choice</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="games">
      <option> -- </option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      </select>

      </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input id="btn-prev" name="prev" type="prev" value="Prev">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <input id="btn-next" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next"></div>
```

**Handler.php**

```
<?php

$name_error = null;

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
{  
  if(empty($_POST["name"]))  
  {  
       $name_error = "Please Enter Name";  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["name"]))  
       {  
            $name_error = "Only Letters and whitespace";  
       }  
   }    
  if($name_error != null) {
     header("Location: capture.php?message=".$name_error.");
}  
?>
```

I changed the validation so your message will get send back to your form. There it checks if an error message is set, if so it will display the error.

Answer (score 0):

be sure to make your form recognize the action file you want to submit.
Edit it the way it looks like this: